# Looking for same values in two different columns in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data

```
dt<-data.table(id=c(1,1,1,1,1),Claimed=c("i","j","i","j","k"),Detected=c("k","j","i","j","i"))
> dt
   id Claimed Detected
1:  1       i        k
2:  1       j        j
3:  1       i        i
4:  1       j        j
5:  1       k        i
```

Now, for each element in `"Claimed"` column, I want to check if it is same in `"Detected"` column and get the percentage of similarity. So, ideally my output would be the following for the above data table.

```
> dt
   id Claimed   Percentage
1:  1       i           50 
2:  1       j          100
3:  1       k            0
```

I tried to reshape the data and get all the `"Detected"` variables for each unique element in `"Claimed"` like below and count the occurrences of `"Claimed"` variable in new `"Detected_modified"` column and thus getting the percentage.

```
> dt
   id Claimed Detected_modified
1:  1       i               k,i
2:  1       j               j,j
3:  1       k                 i
```

But, I strongly believe there would be a simpler solution using data.table which I am not able to figure out in this situation. Can someone please have a try at it ?

**EDIT** :

The levels of factors in the `Detected` and `Claimed` columns are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

dt %>% group_by(id, Claimed) %>%
       summarise(percentage = 100 * sum(Claimed == Detected) / n( ))
```

Edit: if you cant compare due to differing factor levels:

```
dt %>% group_by(id, Claimed) %>%
       summarise(percentage = 100 * sum(as.character(Claimed) == as.character(Detected)) / n( ))
```

Comment: This solution is perfect and nice. I forgot to mention that levels of factors for my columns are different and thus we cannot do `Claimed==Detected` here. I am updating my question. So. changing them to characters helped me !

Comment: you can wrap the Claimed and Detected calls in as.character(), which should fix it